# Website URL - how does stack overflow work?

Tags: url, web

I am not sure on how to search this on google.  Maybe someone could explain instead.  How does a website, like stack overflow, have urls "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/..somenumber../the-title-of-the-question-or-something-like-that

and its able to bring up that webpage with that question.  Could someone explain to me how that is done? Is it some form of javascript?  I was trying to think through this problem and how it would be done, but it confuses me.  I am also a rookie when it comes to web development.

Answer (score 6):

StackOverflow uses the [ASP.Net MVC Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381412.aspx), which allows you to create arbitrary URL routes that are handled by action methods.

You can also do this using [ASP.Net routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx); similar frameworks are available for other platforms.

On a lower level, the browser sends a request to the web server containing an arbitrary path; the server can do whatever it wants to with that path to send a response.
There is no intrinsic relation between paths in URLs and a filesystem.

Most webservers will usually serve the contents of the file at the path, but this is not required.

Comment: Sweet,  Thank you for the answer.  I was wondering on this function works.  Since there would have to be some sort of file (in my mind) for that to work.  But since its a ASP.NET framework, it all makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: @Michael: The same is possible in any other framework or webserver.

Comment: @Michael: A web server maps paths to specific resources.  That resource doesn't have to be a file.

Comment: @Michael: You can do the same with an Apache server by using the mod_rewrite module. This requires some knowledge of regular expressions.

Comment: @Brendan, it hardly needs any any knowledge of mod_rewrite. You can redirect/rewrite everything to x.php and use php to parse $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] any way you want.

Answer (score 2):

That "somenumber" is the ID of the question in the database. Anything that comes after the somenumber/ is for SEO purposes. That's why all these links work.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229090/website-url-how-does-stack-overflow-work
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229090
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229090/foobar
```

Its just referencing that ID to pull up the question

Comment: To be completely fair to SO, it's also beneficial to users to have some informative text in the URL, it's not just an SEO play.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of SO, a server side process extracts the question number (4229090) from the URL and ignores the rest (website-url-how-does-stack-overflow-work). It uses the number for database lookups.

There are lots of different ways to extract that number. The specifics depend on your programming environment.